# estou tentando fazer um select aqui mais ta dando esse problema Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object na linha 49

Tags: php, mvc

```
 // essa função vai retornar um select de um determinado modelo
 public static function getResultSetFromSelect($where = [], $colunas = '*') {
    $sql = "SELECT ${colunas} FROM "
        . static::$nome_tabela
        . static::getFilters($where);
    $resultado = Database::getResultFromQuery($sql);
    if($resultado->num_rows==0){
        return null;
    } else {
        return $resultado;
    }
}

public static  function getAll($where=[],$colunas='*'){
    $objects=[];
    $resultado=static::getResultSetFromSelect($where,$colunas); 

    // se não tiver nenhum objetto ele retorna o  array vaziu e se tiver ele retorna todos os objetos criados
    if($resultado){
        // o metodo get_called_class vai dizer exatamente qual metodo chamou a função getAll
        $class=get_called_class();
        while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($objects,new $class($row));
        }
    }

    return $objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static function getFilters($where) {
    $sql = '';
    if(count($where) > 0) {
        $sql .= " WHERE 1 = 1";
        foreach($where as $column => $value) {
            if($column == 'raw') {
                $sql .= " AND {$value}";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND ${column} = " . static::getFormatedValue($value);
            }
        }
    } 
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: era um problema no getFilters